# Altium 20 autoroute via polygon

Tags: pcb, altium, via, autorouter

I wonder how can I make Altium autorouter to place a short track and then use via to connect SMD IC pads on one side to a polygon on another side?

Should I define any rules?

Should I change any preferences?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would create test points (in the schematic) that are the width of the traces with nothing but copper for the footprint, then place them where you want the traces to go. (not a great solution but one that works). If the autorouter sees the pads in the polygon then it will try to route the traces there.

However, the autorouter is difficult to use and does not do what you want it to, I've found it's easier to use the multi route option and route by hand.

Comment: +1 on routing by hand. The autorouter and even the multi-route tool are very finicky and often don't get you the results you want in the amount of time you can simply do it yourself.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with autorouters is they don't know *what the signal is* so they'll route analog signals right next to digital ones. A human is smarter than that.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Not an automated solution, were I to use that one, no need to place a question. Want to force autorouter to follow his MASTER orders.